# Angular 2: forbidden error 403

Tags: angular

¿Por qué recibo error 403 en firebug al querer representar una imagen?.

Está realizándose la aplicación con MEAN Stack.

Este es el método para el servicio de artista:

```
getArtist(token, id: string){
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization': token
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this._http.get(this.url + 'getOneArtist/'+ id, options).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Y quiero poner su imagen correspondiente. El caso es que en principio todo ha ido bien hasta ahora, puesto que tengo en el back-end configuradas las cabeceras. CORS.

Aquí está el HTML:

```
<div class="image-for-edit" *ngIf="artist.image && artist.image != 'null'">
    <img src="{{url + 'getImageArtist/' + artist.image}}">
</div>
```

Y finalmente, el método del controlador:

```
getArtist(){
    this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        let id = params['id'];

        this._artistService.getArtist(this.token, id).subscribe(
            response => {
                if(!response.artist) {
                    this._router.navigate(['/']);
                }else{
                    this.artist = response.artist;
                }
            },
            error => {
                var errorMessage = <any>error;
                if(errorMessage != null) {
                    console.log(error);
                }   
            }
        );
    });
}
```

¿Alguna pista de por qué todos los sitios en los que quiero poner una imagen no he tenido problema y aquí sí?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo a mi misma pregunta, puesto que he encontrado una solución. Pero no sé si habrá sido un parche para salvar el error un rato, o está hecho de forma correcta.

El caso es que yo uso un middleware para la autorización de usuarios. Y en el back-end tenía esto en el archivo de rutas:

```
router.get(
  '/getImageArtist/:imageFile', 
  md_auth.ensureAuth, 
  ArtistController.getImageArtist
);
```

Esa era una de las rutas definidas. De acuerdo a lo que os podéis imaginar, es la ruta para poder obtener el archivo de imagen correspondiente a cada artista registrado.

Pues aquí estaba el problema, puedes incluir middlewares en la ruta, y yo tenia metido el middleware de autorización de usuario, lo que hacía, a mi entender, que no pudiese obtener ese archivo.

Una vez borrado ese trocito, todo funciona y la imagen se puede visualizar.

Me gustaría que, si alguien ha leído esto y cree que no estoy en lo correcto o podría realizar otro procedimiento lo comentase. No sé si estoy totalmente en lo cierto, aunque veo que funciona, y no quiero influenciar mal al resto de usuarios.